# Should I undelete a question with answers that was deleted by the original OP?

Tags: discussion

I made some effort [to give a detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698603/rails-cant-delete-comments/34698774#34698774) to this question. When the OP got their answer, they marked it as accepted, thanked me in the comments, and then went on to delete the question a minute or so later. I suspect the user was able to delete it because my answer has no up-votes.

I'm disappointed because I made a genuine effort to help the OP, not only with the original problem but with a few other issues as well.

This deflates my enthusiasm. I know this might sound selfish, but I feel like someone took the jam out of my donut after feeling satisfied that I could help.

I have enough rep to undelete the question, but would that be the right thing to do?

Comment: @Paulie_D:  It's not self-answered.

Comment: But the answer there is on point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that they *thanked* you and deleted the question is eerie to me.

The question itself has an upvote, and your answer may be useful to others, so I say that it should be undeleted.  Hopefully the system still keeps this incident in mind for the OP; deleting a question after someone's answered it is very much frowned upon.

Comment: Put in the second vote. Luckily, running out of undelete-votes is *really* hard.

Comment: Most common case of such deletion (hiding homework) doesn't seem to apply... really strange.